# Get max date in Hive

Tags: hive

I have below query

```
SELECT MAX(C.EFCTV_DT) FROM lk1 C,lk2 B WHERE  
C.MKT_cd = B.MKT_cd AND C.RC_TYPE_CD = 'SYAS' AND 
C.TIER_CD = B.TIER_CD AND                                                         C.EFCTV_DT <= '2016-02-02'
```

I am trying to fetch greatest date less than the given date '2016-02-02'. Hive doesn't support Max. Advise pls?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Base Table]

If i want to find the MAX reldate less than  than some date, I will use this

```
select reldate from Base where reldate < '2014-11-09'  ORDER BY reldate LIMIT 1.
```

This may not be the best solution , An alternative way is to write a Give UDF which is very simple.